# Get referer from iphone/android application

Tags: php, android, iphone

I have a web page, that i want to detect if the user redirect from any site in the web or from an iphone/android application.

How can i do this in PHP

Thanks

Comment: If the user surf to my webpage from google (for example) I wan't to know that he came from google (using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]).
But if the user surf to my webpage by redirect from iphone/android application thier is no $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. So how can I know that he redirect from this? 
If I using the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] I will get "iphone" - but it can be that he just using safari on iphone. 
I wan't to detecet when he came from application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explain what you want clearly. Basically, to do something like this you need to check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` attribute of the HTTP header that you are receiving and filter on `Android` or `iPhone` keywords.

Comment: Sorry.
If the user surf to my webpage from google (for example) i wan't to know that he came from google (using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])
But if the user surf to my webpage by redirect from iphone/android application thier is no $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. So how can i know that he redirect from this?
If I using the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] I will get "iphone" - but it can be that he just using safari on iphone. I wan't to detecet when he came from application

Comment: There isn't going to be a referrer since it's the same as opening the browser and typing it in.  There's nothing to refer.  If it's your application, append the URL with `?from=my_iphone_app` or something like that.  If it's not your app, then you would have to talk to the developer.